# How would you flip a right triangle horizontally such that the hypotenuse is on the left side, using for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

[image]

I am supposed to flip the triangle I got in the image above horizontally, such that the hypotenuse is on the left side and not the right. I have tried for quite long and cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: use spaces to move `T` in row to correct place. Or use string formatting - [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Hi Arham, Instead of an image, put your code in the problem so, one can make the changes required.

Comment: Use two for loops instead, one for T and one for space.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you just want the mirror of the output you have got. Try the below code;

```
total = 0
limit = 8
x = range(limit,0,-1)
for i in x:
    total = (' '* i ) + 'T'*(limit - i)
    print(total,end = '\n\n')
```

Output:

```
       T

      TT

     TTT

    TTTT

   TTTTT

  TTTTTT

 TTTTTTT
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach, preserving the code you already have, would be to use a format specification to pad and right align the output:

```
total = 0
x = range(1, 8)

for i in x:
    total = 'T' * i
    print("{:>8}".format(total), end='\n\n')
```

It's worth one's time to learn the various transformations that `print()` and `str.format()` can perform:

```
> python3 test.py
       T

      TT

     TTT

    TTTT

   TTTTT

  TTTTTT

 TTTTTTT

>
```